# QML PolarChart point label on hover

Tags: charts, qml, label, hover, tooltip

There is that QML PolarChart example. (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/images/examples_qmlpolarchart1.png)

As you see, those points are nameless. What I want is to see what exact point's values are by hovering over or clicking it.
There is an option to show labels for all points, but since in my project there are too much of them, I need to show only one particular point label. Or tooltip over it.

Are there any built-in options to do it for series or points?
Maybe there is a way to determine point by hovering over it using "onHovered" signal for series component?
Qt5.15 is available for me. No Qt6.

Comment: PolarChartView documentations shows https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-polarchartview-members.html. In particular the mapToPosition and mapToValue methods. Did you try those?

Comment: I implemented what I wanted using separate ToolTip component and mapToPosition method for AreaSerias's onHovered handler to position it. But I wonder if there is more accurate and smart way to do it. My way looks more like a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would solve your question (basically your solution). I just want to confirm that it is not a workaround, what makes you feel this way? You use the functionality that is provided by the ChartView types to solve your task.

By using the [`hovered(point point, bool state)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-xyseries.html#hovered-signal) signal you can handle when a point is hovered (`state = true`) and loses hover again (`state = false`). Using the [`mapToPosition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#mapToPosition-method) function given by the `ChartView` you can convert the data point into a position to assign that to the `ToolTip`.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtCharts 2.15

ChartView {
    id: chart
    width: 640
    height: 480
    antialiasing: true

    ToolTip {
        id: toolTip
        visible: false
    }

    ScatterSeries {
        id: scatter
        name: "Scatter"
        axisX: ValueAxis { min: 1; max: 3 }
        axisY: ValueAxis { min: 1; max: 2.5 }

        XYPoint { x: 1.5; y: 1.5 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.5; y: 1.6 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.57; y: 1.55 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.8; y: 1.8 }
        XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 1.6 }
        XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 1.3 }
        XYPoint { x: 2.5; y: 2.1 }

        onHovered: function(point, state) {
            toolTip.text = point.x + ", " + point.y
            toolTip.visible = state
            let p = chart.mapToPosition(point, scatter)
            toolTip.x = p.x
            toolTip.y = p.y - toolTip.height
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

To get the ToolTips for the upper series of an `AreaSeries` only you would need to listen to the signal of this exact `LineSeries` as shown below. Unfortunately the `point` that is given as the parameter of the `LineSeries` hovered signal depends on where you put the mouse cursor at and isn't restricted to the provided points only as with a `ScatterSeries`. So you usually get interpolated points with a lot of decimal places. You could work around that by drawing a `ScatterSeries` on top of the `AreaSeries` and use the `hovered` signal from that series instead. If you want that though you could round the values for smaller tool tips.

```
PolarChartView {
    id: chart
    title: "Some Polar Area Series"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    legend.visible: false
    antialiasing: true

    ToolTip {
        id: toolTip
        visible: false
    }

    ValueAxis { id: axis1 }
    ValueAxis { id: axis2 }

    LineSeries {
        id: lowerLine
        axisAngular: axis1
        axisRadial: axis2

        // Please note that month in JavaScript months are zero based, so 2 means March
        XYPoint { x: 0;  y: 15 }
        XYPoint { x: 2;  y: 35 }
        XYPoint { x: 3;  y: 50 }
        XYPoint { x: 5;  y: 75 }
        XYPoint { x: 6;  y: 102 }
        XYPoint { x: 9;  y: 132 }
        XYPoint { x: 10;  y: 100 }
        XYPoint { x: 12;  y: 120 }
        XYPoint { x: 16;  y: 140 }
        XYPoint { x: 20;  y: 150 }
    }
    LineSeries {
        id: upperLine
        axisAngular: axis1
        axisRadial: axis2

        // Please note that month in JavaScript months are zero based, so 2 means March
        XYPoint { x: 0; y: 30 }
        XYPoint { x: 2; y: 55 }
        XYPoint { x: 3; y: 80 }
        XYPoint { x: 5; y: 105 }
        XYPoint { x: 6; y: 125 }
        XYPoint { x: 9; y: 160 }
        XYPoint { x: 10; y: 140 }
        XYPoint { x: 12; y: 140 }
        XYPoint { x: 16; y: 170 }
        XYPoint { x: 20; y: 200 }

        onHovered: function(point, state) {
            toolTip.text = point.x + ", " + point.y
            toolTip.visible = state
            let p = chart.mapToPosition(point, upperLine)
            toolTip.x = p.x
            toolTip.y = p.y - toolTip.height
        }
    }

    AreaSeries {
        axisAngular: axis1
        axisRadial: axis2
        lowerSeries: lowerLine
        upperSeries: upperLine
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just thought there is something like "toolTipEnable" field for Series or Points components.
I use in my PolarChartView AreaSeries component with upperSeries and lowerSeries fields filled with LineSeries; "onHovered" handler works only for AreaSeries and not for LineSeries. But I need toolTips to be shown only for upperSeries. Do you know the way to define wich field is being hovered over?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope the answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented what I wanted using separate ToolTip component and mapToPosition method for AreaSeries's onHovered handler to position it. But I wonder if there is more accurate and smart way to do it. My way looks more like a workaround.

Here is a piece of code for PolarChartView AreaSeries's onHovered handler:

```
onHovered: (point) =>
                 {
                   toolTipID.show(Math.round(point.x)+" "+Math.round(point.y));
                   var pp = chartID.mapToPosition(point);
                   toolTipID.x = pp.x;
                   toolTipID.y = pp.y;
                 }
```

And this is a separate ToolTip component:

```
ToolTip
  {
    id: toolTipID
    timeout: 2000
  }
```

Comment: It is not clear if this is an answer or a new question. If you have a question please ask a new one, or update you existing question with an  edit.

Comment: This is one way to answer my question. If there are other ways to answer it, should I ask it again?

Comment: This sentence is the problem: "But I wonder if there is more accurate and smart way to do it." which makes the answer into a question! However, asking this as written would get your (new) question closed as requiring an opinion. Best to remove the problematic wording and find a new way to ask what you need,